# Android Service, Broadcast and Beacon

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, ibeacon-android

I'm doing a Android App that can read iBeacons and show me a card information about. At my first intent and using the library of  the gotten beacon(easiBeacon), I succeeded that, but now this app got bigger and I need to read the beacons, ask for an equivalent UUID on a web connection meanwhile the app is reading a GPS position.

The question is: how do I do that?
Which is the best way to do this?
I know that I have to create a service but is the only thing I'm sure. 
do I create a Service to read the iBeacons and another one for GPS?

That is it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a single Service that gets updated GPS information and beacon information in the background.  An Android `Service` class is structured similarly to an `Activity` class, but it requires a different Manifest declaration and startup code.  It also has a very different lifecycle, allowing you to run it longer periods of time in the background.

Doing all of this is a pretty big hurdle for a beginner.  I would read up on how Android Services work [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), then make a simple service that works without beacons or GPS.  Then get your beacons and GPS working in the Activity class, and move them to the Service once you have that working.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I'm still having problems with this,. Mu Beacons is already working on the main activity, but when I try to run it on the service, the app closes. Is true that is a big thing for a beginner but it is a sort of mini job I've got, so I must finish it. Until now no problem, but this background process is really new to me.